# Browsing with Tor bundle and without at the same time

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, browsers

I'd like to know how safe is it to use the Tor-browser-bundle (for linux, in case it matters) at the same time as another browser (firefox, in case it matters) normally installed, and why.
Now I am closing it, but often I would rather not close it. I haven't found but one and unclear answer to this.

More generally I would like to know if other internet traffic: amule, email clients, social software (pidgin) etc. that are not configured to use Tor (I understand they shouldn't) should be stopped when using the Tor browser bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about using other protocols at the same time, but browsing the same website at the same time with and without Tor is discouraged because it would be easy for site owner to find your Tor IP and non Tor IP through miss and match.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't browse the *same* web sites with both browsers, and you don't login to any account, there is no correlation. Any non-Tor traffic that has *no relation* to your Tor traffic will not compromise your Tor traffic. As soon as you connect to the same destination with and without Tor, they might figure out that these connections are from the same person.

If you login to an account through Tor, that you have created or previously logged in to *without* Tor, then you lose anonymity.

If you send unencrypted login credentials through Tor, then your account may be compromised. There is no problem using Tor for email and chat, as long as the services use encryption (ssl/tls). (Otherwise you transmit unencrypted credentials and content.)